# Problem with Pointers

Tags: c, linux

I am new to linux c programming and i have a simple program just for learning and when i compile it it gives me error "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" here is my code

```
struct Node
{
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* middle;
    struct Node* right;
    int nodeData;
    int nodeLevel;
    char isVisted;
};
struct ListNode
{
    struct Node* data;
    struct ListNode* next;
};

struct List
{
    struct NodeList* head;
    struct NodeList* tail;
    int count;
};

typedef struct ListNode ListNode;
typedef struct Node Node;
typedef struct List List;

ListNode* InitListNode(Node* data)
{
    ListNode* listNode=(ListNode*)calloc(1,sizeof(ListNode));
    listNode->data=data;
    listNode->next=NULL;
    return listNode;
}

List* InitList()
{
    List* list=(List*)calloc(1,sizeof(List));
    list->count=0;
    list->head=list->tail=NULL;
}

void EnQue(Node* data,List* que)
{
    if(que->count==0)
    {
        que->tail=que->head=InitListNode(data);
        que->count++;
    }
    else
    {
        que->tail->next=InitListNode(data); //here error is problem comes 
        que->tail=que->tail->next;//here error is problem comes
        que->count++;
    }
}
```

please help..

Comment: What line is that error showing up on?

Comment: In the List struct, where is the NodeList type declared? You dereference the variables of that type later.

Comment: `"ListNode* listNode=(ListNode*)calloc(1,sizeof(ListNode));` is poor coding. Its not _wrong_ or anything, just bad C. Use `ListNode* listNode = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));` and remember to check that `listNode != NULL`.

Comment: Where is NodeList defined in struct List?. I see ListNode but not NodeList. Are you getting any compile warnings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

head and tail in struct List are of type NodeList. Should be ListNode?

Comment: thanx a lot solution works.. but one thing why compiler don't give any error stating that NodeList does not exist as i havn't created this struct.

Comment: NodeList does exist - but only as an incomplete type. In your case this translates to "a struct whose members have not been specified yet". And that's exactly what the compiler told you.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is a typo in your definition of `List`.  I believe it should be `ListNode`, which is defined, instead of `NodeList` which is not defined.  Try the following

```
struct List
{
    struct ListNode* head;
    struct ListNode* tail;
    int count;
};
```